# Techniques for evaluating probability integral

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution

Consider the integral of a normal distribution:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x=c
$$

and a second integral for the expected value: 
$$
\int_a^b x\cdot f(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
Since you know the first integral is equal to $c$, what is a good way to evaluate the second integral to find the expected value? Integration by parts doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\int_a^b \frac1c f(x)\,dx = 1.
$$
Therefore $\dfrac1c f(x)$ is a probability density function on the interval $[a,b]$.  It is the **conditional** probability density of a normal random variable **given** that it's in that interval.  So
$$
\int_a^b \frac1c x f(x)\,dx
$$
is the **conditional** expected value of a normal random variable **given** that it's in that interval.

**Later note:** To see why this is the conditional distribution, consider the problem of finding the conditional probability $\Pr(X\in S\mid a\le X\le b)$, where $X$ is a random variable whose density is $f$:
$$
\Pr(X\in S\mid a\le X\le b) = \frac{ \Pr(X\in S\text{ and }a\le X\le b ) }{\Pr(a\le X\le b)}
$$
$$
= \frac{ \Pr(X\in S\text{ and }a\le X\le b ) }{c} = \frac{\int_{S\cap [a,b]} f(x)\,dx}{c} = \int_{(\text{the relevant set})} \frac1c f(x)\,dx.
$$