# Joint distribution of integer and fractional part of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Here's the set up:**

Let the random variable $X$ have the following distribution

$$f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-x} & \quad \text{if}\hspace{2mm} 0<x<\infty\\
    0 & \quad \text{elsewhere.}
  \end{cases} $$
Let $Y=[X]$ be the integer part and $Z=X-[X]$ be the fractional part.

**Problem:**

I'm supposed to find the joint distribution function of $Y$ and $Z$, and the moment generating function of $Y$. I think I have the mgf of $Y$, but don't really know how to approach finding the joint distribution.

**My inner dialogue:**

It seems like to find  $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq t)$, we'll be summing $e^{-x}$ in $x$ over the integers up to $\lfloor t \rfloor$. On the other hand, with $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t)$, will we integrate, just skipping integers?  But $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(Z< t)$ if $Z$ is continuous? Hmm...

I would very much appreciate any suggestions on how to get started here.

Also, this isn't homework.

Comment: If $t$ is an integer, $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = \mathbb{P}( \lfloor X \rfloor \leq t) = \mathbb{P} ( X < t+1) = \int_0^{t+1} e^{-x}\, dx$, not summing at the integer points.

Comment: The integer and fractional parts are independent, and that's about 98% of the answer.  See my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely misinterpreted the set up.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but just to state what $Y, Z$ should be.

If $t$ is an integer, $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) = \mathbb{P}( \lfloor X \rfloor \leq t) = \mathbb{P} ( X < t+1) = \int_0^{t+1} e^{-x}\, dx$, not summing at the integer points.

If $0 \leq r \leq 1$, then $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq r) = \mathbb{P}( X - \lfloor X \rfloor < r) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P} (n < X < n+r)$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the conditional distribution of the fractional part given that the integer part is $3$.  That's the conditional distribution of $X-3$ given that $3\le X<4$.  The conditional distribution of $X$ itself, given that it's in that interval has density $ce^{-x}$ for $3\le x<4$ and $0$ outside that interval.  Translating that $e$ units leftward, we get $ce^{-(x+3)}$ $=(ce^{-x}\cdot\text{another constant})$.  All probability densities on $[0,1)$ that are proportional to $e^{-x}$ on that interval and $0$ elsewhere are the same!

Therefore, the conditional distribution of the fraction part given that the integer part is $3$ is the same as the conditional distribution of the fraction part given that the integer part is anything else.  In other words: **the two are independent.**

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely follow. Why does the conditional distribution of $X$, given that it's in the interval have $ce^{-x}$ as its density?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I think I got it. I like this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I recently answered that same question about conditional densities here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278762/techniques-for-evaluating-probability-integral/278766#278766

Answer (score 0):

From
\begin{align}
P[Y=n,Z\leq z]&=P[n\leq X< n+z]=\int^{z+n}_ne^{-x}\,dx\\
& =e^{-n}-e^{-n-z}=e^{-n}(1-e^{-z})\\
&=(1-e^{-1})e^{-n}\frac{1-e^{-z}}{1-e^{-1}}
\end{align}
It follows that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables, and that
$Y\sim\operatorname{Geo}(e^{-1})$, $Z$ has an absolutely continuous distribution (w.r.t the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$) with destiny
$$f_Z(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{1-e^{-1}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}$$