# Show that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and find their distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that $X\sim\exp(\lambda=1)$. Let $Y$ be the integer part and $Z$ be the fractional part. Show that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and find their distributions.

This one is kinda confusing. Any help?

Comment: Hint: exponential distribution is memoryless.

Comment: Thank you, but do you understand what it means by integer part and fractional part?

Comment: Yes. Integer part of $X$ (noted as $[X]$) is the largest integer no greater than $X$. Fractional part of $X$ (noted as $\{X\}$) is $X-[X]$. So you know that $[X]\le X<[X]+1$.

Comment: @A.S. : It is also (and in recent decades more frequently) denoted $\lfloor X\rfloor$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Indeed - and I think the new notation is better as it explicitly suggests what a function does. But I didn't know at the time how to LaTeX the floor symbol and I'm still used to old notation (and old habits die hard).

Comment: @A.S. : Do you know that by right-clicking on mathematical notation set in MathJax on this site, you get a menu from which you can choose to see what the MathJax code is in a particular instance?  You would find \lfloor X\rfloor . ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael - I know - that's why I said "at the time" ;).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279704/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq 0$, we have
$$
\Pr(Y\leq n)=\Pr(X< n+1)=1-e^{-n-1}.
$$
For $z\in[0,1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr(Z\leq z)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\Pr(X\in[m,m+z])\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(\exp(-m)-\exp(-m-z))\\
&=(1-e^{-z})\sum_{m=0}^\infty(1/e)^m\\
&=\frac{e-e^{1-z}}{e-1}
\end{align*}
Finally,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(Y\leq n,Z\leq z)&=\sum_{m=0}^n\Pr(m\leq X\leq m+z)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^n(\exp(-m)-\exp(-m-z))\\
&=(1-e^{-z})\sum_{m=0}^n(1/e)^m
\end{align*}
which you can verify to be equal to $\Pr(Y\leq n)\Pr(Z\leq z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $Y$ is the integer part of random variable $X$, the probability mass distribution for $Y\in\{0,...\}$ is therefore:
$$\begin{align}
p_Y(y) & = \mathsf P(y\leq X < y+1)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1 f_X(y+t)\operatorname d t
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf e^{-\lambda y}\cdot\int_0^1 \mathsf e^{-\lambda t}\operatorname d t
\\[1ex] & = \underline{\qquad}
\end{align}$$

---

Because $Z$ is the fractional part of the random variable $X$, the probability density distribution for $Z\in[0;1)$ is

$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) & = \sum_{t\in\Bbb Z} f_X(s+z)
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{t=0}^1 \lambda\mathsf e^{-\lambda(t+z)}
\\[1ex] & = \lambda\, \mathsf e^{-\lambda z} \sum_{t=0}^\infty {(e^{-\lambda})}^t
\\[1ex] & = \underline{\qquad}
\end{align}$$

---

The joint mass-density is:

$$p_{Y,Z}(y,z) = f_{X}(y+z) = \lambda\,\mathsf e^{-\lambda(y+z)}$$

Because the joint event of $Y=y$ and $Z=z$ uniquely describes $X=y+z$, since any real is the sum of an *unique* pair of an integer and a unit-interval real.    $\forall x\in \Bbb R\; \exists! y\in \Bbb Z\; \exists! z\in [0;1]\;\big(x=y+z\big)$

---

So clearly: $p_{Y,Z}(y,z) = p_Y(y)\;f_Z(z)$ and thus the random variables $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.