# Probability density function of an exponential minus its integer part:

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have an exponential distribution $X\sim exp(\lambda)$, and another distribution $T=$ $X - \lfloor{X}\rfloor$ and I need to find the pdf the random variable T.

I know the pdf of $\lfloor{X}\rfloor$, which is $P(\lfloor{X}\rfloor = k) =(1-e^{-\lambda})(e^{-\lambda k})$.

Here's what I did up until now:

$F_T = P(T\leq t) = P(X-\lfloor{X}\rfloor \leq t) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty P( X \leq t +k | \lfloor{X}\rfloor =k) = $
$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{P( X \leq t +k , \lfloor{X}\rfloor =k)}{P(\lfloor{X}\rfloor =k)}$

But I am pretty sure $X$ and $\lfloor{X}\rfloor$ aren't independent which means I don't really know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply use the definition of $T$? Which tells you that, for every $t$ in $(0,1)$, $$\{T\leqslant t\}=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{n\leqslant X\leqslant n+t\}$$

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked, posting solution below.

Comment: Well done. The result is correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513793/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found a solution thanks to a comment, here it is:

$$ P(T\leq t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty P(n \leq X \leq n + t) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {F_X(n+t)-F_X(n)}$$
hence
$$P(T\leq t) =
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty [1-e^{-\lambda(n+t)} - (1-e^{\lambda n})]=  \frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}- \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda t}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

Thus, on $(0,1)$, the density is:

$$ f_T(t)= \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$