# Distribution of fractional part of exponential random variable conditioned on floor

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am working with the following question, which asks for the type of distribution.

Let $X$ be a random variable of distribution Exp($\lambda$). Let $\{x\},\ \lfloor x\rfloor$ denote the fractional part and the integer part of $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which type of distribution does $\{x\}$ have conditional on $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

I have calculated the cumulative distribution function $$F(\theta|k)=\mathbb{P}\left(\{x\}<\theta\ |\ \lfloor x\rfloor = k\right) = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda\theta}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$
However, I have searched for many types of distributions and none of them matched this one. I would be really grateful if someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: ${X}\mid \lvert X\rvert$ is equal in distribution to $X\mid X\in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Fractional part and integer part are independent: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513793/321264.