# If $X$ is an exponential random variable, does that mean $\lfloor X\rfloor$ and $X -\lfloor X\rfloor$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing, independence

I've derived an expression for $P\{\lfloor X\rfloor= n, X -\lfloor X\rfloor\leq x\}$ to be $e^{-\lambda(n)}[1 - e^{-\lambda(x)}]$,

and when I find an expression for $P(\lfloor X\rfloor= n)P(X  \leq x+n)$,

I have the two expressions aren't equal. Is this enough to say they aren't independent?

Comment: They are indeed independent. Have a look here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279704/joint-distribution-of-integer-and-fractional-part-of-random-variable?.

Comment: Did you *prove* the two expressions aren't equal? Often, people make the mistake of thinking two formulas that look different must be unequal.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513793/321264