# Integer and Fractional Parts of a Uniform Random Variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have some questions of this link (Calvin Lin's answer): [Joint distribution of integer and fractional part of random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279704/joint-distribution-of-integer-and-fractional-part-of-random-variable/4743431#4743431)

Why PMF for the integer part is equal to an integral? If PMF is for discrete it would be a SUM. Same way for PDF of the fractional part is a SUM if PDF is continuous it would be an integral?

Additional info:
In my case: X= $\lfloor X \rfloor$ + frac(X) and X is continuos and uniform [0,k]

Some could help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has a law that is absolutely continuous with respect Lebesgue's measure (i.e. the law of $X$ has a density $f_X$), $Y=\lfloor X\rfloor$ and $Z=X=Y$, then
$$P[Y=n,Z\leq  z]=P[n\leq  X\leq z+n]=\int^{z+n}_n f_X(x)\,dx$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0<z<1$.

- If $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,k)$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then for $0\leq n<k$
  $$
  P[Y=n,Z\leq z]=\frac1kz$$
  This means that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, $Y$ is discrete and uniformly distributed in $\{0,\ldots, k-1\}$ and $Z\sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$.
- The case where $k\in(1,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ can be treated similarly, however $Y$ and $Z$ are no longer independent.
  For $0\leq n<\lfloor k\rfloor$ and $0<z<1$ we have that
  $$P[Y=n,Z\leq z]=P[n\leq X\leq n+z]=\frac{1}{k}z$$
  and for $n=\lfloor k\rfloor$ we have that
  \begin{align}
  P[Y=n,Z\leq z]&=P[\lfloor k\rfloor< X\leq \min(k,\lfloor k\rfloor+z)]\\
  &=\frac{1}{k}\big(\min(k,\lfloor k\rfloor+z)]-\lfloor k\rfloor\big) =\frac{k-\lfloor k\rfloor}{k}\frac{\min(k,\lfloor k\rfloor+z)-\lfloor k\rfloor}{k-\lfloor k\rfloor}
  \end{align}
  Hence, on $\{0\leq Y<\lfloor k\rfloor\}$ the conditional distribution of $Z|Y$ is  $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$, and on $\{Y=\lfloor k\rfloor\}$,  the distribution of
  $Z|Y$ is  $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,k-\lfloor k\rfloor)$.

Comment: and how do you know Z is uniform from 0 to 1? I think this is intuitively but i want to know in mathematical way

Comment: @LVN: when $k>1$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then adding over $0\leq n<\lfloor k\rfloor$ yields $\sum^{\lfloor k\rfloor-1}_{n=0}P[Y=n,Z\leq z]=z$.

Answer (score 0):

The integer part will be discrete, meaning you would get a sum. The fractional part is continuous except in natural numbers, since you look for $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq t)$, it will be discontinuous in a finite amount of points, so you can calculate the integral from discontinuous point to discontinuous point to get a finite sum of integrals. In practice this is just written as an integral.

Comment: I know the integer part will be discrete(Y) and the frac will be continuos(Z) but i dont know how to calculate PMF Y and PDF Z?

Comment: PDF Z is the same as PDF X except that it has no value on the integers

Comment: PMF doesn't make sense on continuous distributions.